# print sum based on a value of specific column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file.

```
Name ID Savings
RK   1  10000
RS   2  10900
RK   1  1380
RS   2  10200
```

I want to find total savings of two people(RK & RS). so expected result I want is:

```
RK 1 11380  (i.e 10000 + 1380)
RS 2 21100  (i.e 10900 + 10200)
```

Comment: Could you please try to explain a bit more what you're looking at, are those file in a same folder ? Is this content a file, what do yout want precisely, there very few chances anyone answer something that unclear.

Comment: how was `11100` calculated?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation of GNU `awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html) ? You really should, then ask a more focused question. We won't do your homework!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch very rude comment considering the lack of understanding of the poster :D

Comment: No, the OP is expected to make some research before asking. He don't even show any `awk` code in  his question. This is not a "write-my-script" or "do-my-homework" site!

Comment: If you're happy with one of the answers, upvoting it (or several) and maybe even [accepting the most helpful one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) is the best way of saying "Thank You!" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR > 1 { s[$2] += $3; n[$2] = $1 } END { for (i in s) { print n[i], i, s[i] }}' file
RS 2 21100
RK 1 11380
```

We use two arrays, one to hold the sums (`s`) and one to hold the names (`n`). The indexing into the arrays is done using the ID (there could be several people with the same name, so we'll avoid using that as an index).

For each line of input (excluding the header line), we update the sum and store the name.  At the end, we go through the saved information and print it.

Comment: I can clearly understand this command. Thank you so much..

Comment: The command works fine. I wanted to understand the usage of 'END' keyword here. If I dont use 'END' keyword awk 'NR>1{t[$2] += $3;n[$2]=$1} {for (i in t) {print i,n[i],t[i]}}' salary
1 RK 10000
1 RK 10000
2 RS 10900
1 RK 11380
2 RS 10900
1 RK 11380
2 RS 21100 my output is like this. Can you help me understand this?

Comment: @RadhakrishnanRk The `END` block is executed when the input file has ended. Without `END`, you execute the block for _each_ input line (giving you a cumulative sum).

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` for that:

```
awk 'NR>1{seen[$1FS$2]+=$NF} END{for (x in seen) print x, seen[x]}' in
```

This is reading the entire column#1 and column#2 and keep filed separator `FS` intact as well which is whitespace into the array named `seen` and for each uniq combination of `$1FS$2` summing-up the last filed value.

At the end, loop over the array with `x` as variable to travers and first print the `$1FS$2` value and their respective total sum with `seen[x]`.

The `in` would be your input filename. and with `NR>1` we are skipping the header line where its **R**ecord **N**umber =1 `NR>1`.